# Using helper function inside a Core Class in CodeIgniter

Tags: codeigniter, helper

There is a helper which I would like to use inside a core class, CI_Router (MY_Router, to be more accurate). In this custom router, I made some modifications to the original code, in order to be able to insert hyphens into my urls.
I have defined the helper on the autoload.php file, as usual, but it seems that I can´t invoque a helper function inside a class other than a view or controller.

Any ideas about how to handle this? My initial approach was to use a helper, so I can reuse it on any place I want.

TYVM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Helpers are not instantiated until after the core, thus why it does not work.

You will either have to:

1. Duplicate the function in your `MY_Router` class, or,
2. Rethink why you might be using the same function in the Router that you use in a standard controller or view.

Option 1 is obviously easier, but might not be preferable depending on how bad your OCD is.

Comment: ok... choice number one will do for now, I think, because I'm in a hurry. But it would be very nice to know that there is a better way to do it. Thx.

Comment: Take a look at http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/hooks.html - you might be able to use the `pre_system` hook, but you won't have access to any CI stuff, so if your function relies on any of that, then you're out of luck.

Answer (score 0):

You could try getting the instance of the main CI object and setting it to a variable, then load the helper using that. Ex:

```
$ci =& get_instance();
$ci->load->helper('date');
```

I know that works in other areas, not 100% sure about any of the router classes.